# Pass by Value in JSON in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have observed a strange behavior in JSON,

Let me try to describe scenario, we have one angular scope variable say

```
$scope.regValue = 0;
```

This is initialized in controller, and used under **ngModel** in **HTML template** to track down a change in value.

Now Let's assign this to JSON object key,

```
var jsonObj = {
  'key1': $scope.regValue
};
```

What i have observed is, now

```
jsonObj['key1']
```

value will be **0**, which is **Correct**.

But when **ngModel** changes the value of **$scope.regValue**, It is not reflected under JSON key value, which means

```
jsonObj['key1']
```

is still equal to **0**.

While **$scope.regValue** has already changed.

**Is this behavior expected, Or Pass by reference can't pass it's own reference to another variable ?**

Comment: That's the correct behavior.  You're not passing by reference, rather your're assigning a value to `'key1'` nothing else.

Comment: @Ele What can be done to achieve the other behavior in the given scenario ?

Comment: The problem is that sub-directives of the controller are inheriting the $scope of the controller, so the $scope.regValue in the ng-model isn't always the $scope of the controller but the $scope of a subdirective. Always use subobjects or use `ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl"` and `ng-model="$ctrl.regValue"`, and in the controller replace `$scope.regValue` by `this.regValue`.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant,
I am already doing that, To explain i kept it in similar fashion !

Comment: @SHOHILSETHIA look my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in JavaScript between objects and primitive values (strings, numbers, booleans). Primitives are never passed by reference, while objects always are.

So in the case of your object property, you are assigning a numeric value to

```
var jsonObj = {
  'key1': $scope.regValue // this is a number and assigned as such
};
```

When you update a property on the `$scope` object , you are not modifying the value of the `jsonObj` variable.

```js
var $scope = {
  regValue: 0
}

console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.regValue);

var jsonObj = {
  key1: $scope.regValue
}

console.log(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonObj.key1);

$scope.regValue = 5;

console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.regValue);

console.log(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonObj.key1);
```

Try this for comparison :

```
var otherObject = $scope;
```

You will see that `otherObject` reflects all the changes of `$scope`, because it is actually referencing the same object in memory.

```js
var $scope = {
  regValue: 0
}

console.log($scope);

var otherObject = $scope;

$scope.regValue = 5;
console.log($scope);
console.log(otherObject);
```

Comment: $scope.regValue is not primitive $scope is also a json object.

Comment: `$scope.regValue` is a number. When it is assigned to `jsonObj.key1`, the number 0 is assigned, not the `$scope` object.

Comment: but referring to $scope object attribute i.e regValue.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to accomplish that 'second approach', use watchers:**

```
$scope.$watch('regValue', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
   jsonObj['key1'] = newValue ;
});
```

## Examplation of values passed by reference

```
var jsonObj = {
    'key1': $scope.regValue
};

// This function modifies the passed object.
var modify(obj) {
    obj['key1'] = 12122;
};

modify(jsonObj); //jsonObj has a new value because was modified.
```

For instance, if a model (`$scope.regValue`) is attached to a `input-text` and a user enters a new value, the `$digest`'s process will handle that information and assigns that data to the specific model `$scope.regValue`.  Therefore, the object `jsonObj` is not modified because never was processed by the `$digest`.

If you want the attribute `key1` be modified when `$scope.regValue` is modified by any process (i.e: user input), use `watchers`.

## Resource

- [Post: Mastering $watch in AngularJS](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/)

Comment: I understand JSON value is not getting updated,
I have work around in mind like ng-change or replace ngModel value with JSON object key itself like jsonObj.key1,
What i am looking for is, If there is a way to pass by reference in what i am doing above !

Comment: @SHOHILSETHIA No, you won't be able to do that because the `$digest`process won't modify the references of each models.  That's the reason of `$scope.$watch`.

Comment: Shouldn't Javascript handle that ?
Bacause at last in JSON, that scope variable is treated as a value to a key !